# cant pick an element from an array and assign it to a spot in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, type-conversion

i am trying to pick an element form an array and assign it to a spot in a matrix, but every time i try it send this error message  error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

```
public CountLetters(int rows, int cols, String[] vals)
    {
    char matrix[][] = new char[rows][cols];
    
    char[] source = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
     
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){      
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){    
             matrix[i][j] = (int)source[Math.floor(Math.random()*source.length)];    
            }        
        }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void countLetters(int rows, int cols)
{
    char matrix[][] = new char[rows][cols];

    char[] source = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};

    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = source[(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*source.length)];
        }
    }
}
```